# pgfmath expression containing a \newtoks defined via a \def

Tags: pgfmath

This must be another of those expansion related issues as I don't know why the following

```
\def\MaxValueOfTok{8}%
\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}
\SomeTokDefinedViaDef={\MaxValueOfTok}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}%
```

fails with

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `8' or` 8@' (in '10-8').

If possible, would prefer a solution that requires only changing the `\pgfmathsetmacro` computation, and not require any changes to how the token is defined. Alternatively, adjusting how the `\def` is set up would work as well.

Un-commenting the last two lines in the MWE will reproduce the problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% Easy way to get pgfmath

\def\MaxValueOfTok{8}%

\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}
\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}

\SomeTokDefinedDirectly={7}
\SomeTokDefinedViaDef={\MaxValueOfTok}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-5}%
Differerence is \Difference (numerical).

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\MaxValueOfTok}%
Differerence is \Difference (using def).

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedDirectly).

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}%
%Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedViaDef).
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{pgf}` is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do complete expansion beforehand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}% Easy way to get pgfmath

\def\epgfmathsetmacro#1#2{\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pgfmathsetmacro\noexpand#1{#2}}\x}

\def\MaxValueOfTok{8}%

\newtoks\SomeTokDefinedDirectly
\newtoks\SomeTokDefinedViaDef

\SomeTokDefinedDirectly={7}
\SomeTokDefinedViaDef={\MaxValueOfTok}

\begin{document}
\epgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-5}%
Differerence is \Difference (numerical).

\epgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\MaxValueOfTok}%
Differerence is \Difference (using def).

\epgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedDirectly).

\epgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedViaDef).
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to expand it manually, using `10\expandafter-\the\SomeTokDefinedViaDef`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% Easy way to get pgfmath

\def\MaxValueOfTok{8}%

\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}
\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}

\SomeTokDefinedDirectly={7}
\SomeTokDefinedViaDef={\MaxValueOfTok}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-5}%
Differerence is \Difference (numerical).

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\MaxValueOfTok}%
Differerence is \Difference (using def).

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\the\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedDirectly).

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Difference}{10\expandafter-\the\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedViaDef).
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to replace `pgfmath` by `l3fp` from the `l3kernel` bundle.  The parser in `l3fp` takes care of expanding everything; it also unpacks the contents of `\toks` and other registers.  No need for `\the`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Load expl3 for l3fp, and xparse for \NewDocumentCommand.
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\explfpsetmacro} { m m }
  { \tl_set:Nx #1 { \fp_to_tl:n {#2} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%

\def\MaxValueOfTok{8}%

\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}
\newtoks{\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}

\SomeTokDefinedDirectly={7}
\SomeTokDefinedViaDef={\MaxValueOfTok}

\begin{document}
\explfpsetmacro{\Difference}{10-5}%
Differerence is \Difference (numerical).

\explfpsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\MaxValueOfTok}%
Differerence is \Difference (using def).

\explfpsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\SomeTokDefinedDirectly}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedDirectly).

\explfpsetmacro{\Difference}{10-\SomeTokDefinedViaDef}%
Differerence is \Difference (using SomeTokDefinedViaDef).
\end{document}
```

A few things to note:

- at the moment, `pgfmath` provides more functions than `l3fp`;
- computations with `l3fp` are *much* more precise (16 digits floating points, versus the range of TeX's dimensions);
- speed is comparable;
- a few functions will most likely never be implemented for use within `l3fp` expressions, namely box measurements (`\widthof`...) and random numbers.